# EF6 Create DB using SQLite Model First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have created edmx file containing my db schema using SQLite.
When I launch the application, I would like the application to create a new db file. I tried to use Database.CreateIfNotExists(), but it doesn't do anything.

I understand that it is a model first and not a code first. Is it possible to create a new db file for "model first"?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by the provider: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=6b5ef4ff7a and http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=eb0cada674

Comment: Did anything change in these years? Is it still not possible to work with SQLite model first and then create the database?

Comment: You can do it with EF Core now